# How to transform WordPress user role code to WP shortcode?

Tags: shortcode

I want to learn how to create a WordPress shortcode that checks for a user role.

If a WP user has user role 'member1', then show the content. Otherwise, show nothing.

This is the WordPress code I have to check for a user role:

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( in_array( 'member1', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
    //The user has the "member1" role
}
```

I also know how to create a shortcode, like this:

```
add_shortcode( 'check-user-role', 'func_check_user_role' );
func_check_user_role() {

}
```

But how do I combine both into something that works like this
(to check if a user has 'member1' user role:

```
[check-user-role='member1']show this content if the user has user role member1[/check-user-role]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This article in the Plugin Handbook could be helpful "[Shortcodes with Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/shortcodes-with-parameters/)"

Comment: Thank you @user141080. Will read that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a parameter to your shortcode function and use this value to check if the user is allowed to view the content:

```
function func_check_user_role( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_role = $atts['role'];
    $allowed_roles = [];
    array_push($allowed_roles , $user_role);

if ( is_user_logged_in() && array_intersect($allowed_roles, $user->roles ) ) {
      return $content;
 } else {
    return '';
}

}
add_shortcode( 'check-user-role', 'func_check_user_role' );
```

And your shortcode looks like:

```
[check-user-role role="subscriber"] Your content [/check-user-role]
```

---

So the `$atts` are your attributes, the `$content` is your post content.

Check out the documentation:

https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/shortcodes-with-parameters/

You save the value inside of your `$user_role` variable and check, if your user is logged in and has the role which is inside of the user object (you got that in your `$user`). If this is true you return the content. If not true, there is nothing to be returned or maybe a string like "you are not allowed to view this content".

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome example rank! Thanks!!